# Kendo Editor , negative value restriction

Tags: html, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I am working for a project with MVC4.

I am using kendo editor template for `Incell` Editing. Here is a column that is accepting negative value when edited.

**Code I am using**-

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Dev.Crm.Web.Models.ViewModel.ProjectViewModel>()
        .Name("_projectGrid")
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))

        .Columns(columns =>
        {



          columns.Bound(p => p.FixedPrice).Title(@Dev.Crm.Web.Resources.Shared.Project.Label_FixedPrice).EditorViewData(new { OnChangeCallback = "Product_List_updateProjectChanges" }).Width("15%").EditorTemplateName("Number");


        })

        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Selectable()
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource

                        .Ajax() 
.Model(model =>model.Id(p => p.TaskID))
                        .Batch(true)
                                  .Model(model =>
                                  {
                                      model.Id(p => p.ProjectID);
                                      model.Field(p => p.ProjectID).Editable(false);


                                  })
        .Read(read => read.Url(@Url.Project_Operation_Read()).Data("Project_List_searchData"))// the name of the javascript function which will return the additional data.      
                        //.Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Delete", "Project"))
        .Update(update => update.Url(@Url.Project_Operation_SaveCellEdit()))

        )
                          .Events(e => { e.DataBound("Grid_DataBound"); })

      )
```

In cell edit , I can edit this cell, but how do i restrict it from accepting negative values.

Answer (score 1):

Basically I assume that your project has the EditorTemplates under the Shared/EditorTemplate folder. If you have them then for numbers you should use the KendoNumericTextBox widget.

If you do not use the Kendo NumbericTextBox as editor - you better [find how to do it.](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates)

Once you have that editor template applied you can set the **[Min](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/numerictextbox/overview)** option to be equal to 0.